# PDF attachment extraction from SOAP Response using C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, response

How can I **extract PDF attachment** into my local folder (e.g. Downloads folder) from SOAP response in C#?

### SOAP response, Headers:

| Header | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Transfer-Encoding | chunked |
| Server | nginx |
| Connection | keep-alive |
| Content-Encoding | gzip |
| Vary | Accept-Encoding |
| Content-Type | multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:e2d02621-fa95-4d72-a7c3-a364394a2ef5"; start="root.message@cxf.apache.org"; start-info="text/xml" |

### Raw response:

Start of response:

> --uuid:e2d02621-fa95-4d72-a7c3-a364394a2ef5
>
> Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> Content-ID: root.message@cxf.apache.org

```
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:v1="http://www.somepage.com/api/store/v1/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <v1:ResponseHeader state="SUCCEEDED" timelasted="31"/>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <v1:RetrieveDocumentResponse>
        <v1:references>
            <v1:reference>
                <v1:id>9999</v1:id>
                <v1:version>1</v1:version>
            </v1:reference>
        </v1:references>
        <v1:contentCount>1</v1:contentCount>
        <v1:contents>
            <v1:content>
                <v1:name>TestDocument1.pdf</v1:name>
                <v1:mime>application/pdf</v1:mime>
                <v1:data fileSize="34309">
                    <inc:Include
                        xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:99999-9"/>
                    </v1:data>
                </v1:content>
            </v1:contents>
        </v1:RetrieveDocumentResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

> --uuid:e2d02621-fa95-4d72-a7c3-a364394a2ef5
>
> Content-Type: application/pdf
>
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
>
> Content-ID: <99999-9>
>
> ŰžtăŽ:Ř=őŘMűĐ=ąŔĽŔĽŔĽÍŰť´ŰM..here started attachment in some encoding

End of reponse.
I tried to decompress GZIP, but I'm getting exception:

**The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.**

First part of my C# code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
            req.Headers.Add("SOAP:Action");
            req.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.Accept = "application/pdf";
            //req.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
            req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username:password"));
            req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);

            // Set properties for MTOM
            //req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;
            //req.SendChunked = true;

            try
            {
                var soapRequest = @"XMLRequest";
```

Second part:

```
foreach (string part in parts)
    {
      // Check if the part contains PDF content
      if (part.Contains("Content-Type: application/pdf"))
      {
        // Extract and process the PDF content
        Console.WriteLine("Found PDF attachment:");
        Console.WriteLine(part);
        // Find the index where the actual binary data begins
        int dataStartIndex = part.IndexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 4; // "\r\n\r\n" marks are the end of headers

        // Extract the binary data from the part
        // if I use following row, I'm getting the message that is not in Base64 format
        //byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(part.Substring(dataStartIndex));
        byte[] binaryData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(part.Substring(dataStartIndex));

        // Decompress the data
        using (MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream(binaryData))
        using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (MemoryStream decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
          decompressionStream.CopyTo(decompressedStream);
          // Write the decompressed binary data to a file
          File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\USER\Downloads\Example.pdf", decompressedStream.ToArray());
         }
     }
```

Thank you in advance for edited / new C# script!

Comment: Where is the pdf file data?  The pdf should be compressed (gzip) in the body of the respopnse.  All I see is the name of the pdf and not the contents.

Comment: @jdweng Here is it, I kept only this part of it in my question because it was very long, so I cut it:
ŰžtăŽ:Ř=őŘMűĐ=ąŔĽŔĽŔĽÍŰť´ŰM ... weird characters for me.. :-) Do you need something more?

Comment: @KJ Can you describe in detail what you meant? I don't know what is "PK" and "-xf filename". Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the body contain mime attachments? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)  It looks like you are skipping some returns which may be the header to the MIME.  With compression you need to uncompress exactly what was compresses otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: @jdweng I extended my C# code into 2 parts for better understanding what I did in settings of soap header request. Is this what you meant? Thank you in advance!

Comment: UPDATE: Current situation is similar - I'm getting valid response, I'm able to split into particular parts, then extract value of the attachment data, but I absolutely don't know in which encoding/compression it is. I tried gzip, but without success. Base64 its not as well. Then I tried standard binary data, I successfully generated desired PDF file, but Adobe or my browser getting me message, that its broken. (that file)..

Comment: PDF is binary and using encoding on binary data will corrupt the data.  PDF should be a byte[] (not a string).  Either save file using a binary method, or read into a memory stream.  A PDF has an ASCII header and opening with notepad will show the header which will contains the letters "PDF" and version.

Comment: Do you have more than one MIME attachment?  Your code should work.  I suspect you may be getting extra character at the beginning or end.  Maybe Trim the string : part.Substring(dataStartIndex).Trim()

Comment: @jdweng Only one MIME attachment and Trim I tried, without success.

Comment: Save results to a file and then try a zip tool like 7-Zip.  We need to find out first if it can be unpacked.  It is not gzip because you are getting an error when uncompress.  You did not get an error when you tried base64string so it may be combination of more than one method.